# How to declare static and global variable in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am using a function of increase and decrease sharpness, contrast of an image but the problem is that I have to get the value of the increased or decreased sharpness or contrast value from the functions to reuse those values. the function of increase and decrease of sharpness or contrast happens when the button is clicked in the GUI. Kindly help me to use and declare static and global variables which will be used in the application.

**Main GUI File**

```
function varargout = Cotton_Disease_Detector(varargin)
gui_Singleton = 1;
gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                   'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                   'gui_OpeningFcn', @Cotton_Disease_Detector_OpeningFcn, ...
                   'gui_OutputFcn',  @Cotton_Disease_Detector_OutputFcn, ...
                   'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
                   'gui_Callback',   []);
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
    gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
end

if nargout
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
else
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
end

function Cotton_Disease_Detector_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
axes(handles.axes1);
axis off 
axes(handles.axes4);
axis off 
axes(handles.axes5);
axis off
axes(handles.axes6);
axis off 
handles.output = hObject;
guidata(hObject, handles);

function varargout = Cotton_Disease_Detector_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 
varargout{1} = handles.output;

function browse_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
image=browseImage();
imshow(image,'Parent',handles.axes1)

function segmentation_image_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
image = imread('enhance.jpg');
image=imageSegmentation(image);
imshow(image,'Parent',handles.axes5);

function enhance_image_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
image=imread('resize.jpg');
set(handles.enhancementPanel,'Visible','On')
image=imageEnhancement(image);
imwrite(image,'enhance.jpg');
imshow(image,'parent',handles.axes4);

function classification_image_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

function feature_extraction_image_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

function decreaseContrast_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
image=imread('enhance.jpg');
[J,x]=decreaseContrast(image,x);
imwrite(J,'enhance.jpg');
imshow(J,'parent',handles.axes4);

function increaseContrast_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
image=imread('enhance.jpg');
[J,x]=increaseContrast(image,x);
imwrite(J,'enhance.jpg');
imshow(J,'parent',handles.axes4);

function decreaseSharpness_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
image=imread('enhance.jpg');
[J,x]=decreaseSharpness(image,x);
imwrite(J,'enhance.jpg');
imshow(J,'parent',handles.axes4);

function increaseSharpness_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
image=imread('enhance.jpg');
[J,x]=increaseSharpness(image,x);
imwrite(J,'enhance.jpg');
imshow(J,'parent',handles.axes4);

function resizeImage_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
image=imread('read.jpg');
image=resizeImage(image);
imwrite(image,'resize.jpg');
```

**Function of increase Sharpness**

```
function [image,x]  = increaseSharpness(image,x)
if isempty(x)
    x=0.2;
end
x=x+0.2;
image=imsharpen(image,'radius',2,'Amount',x);
end
```

**Function of decrease Sharpness**

```
function [image,x]  = decreaseSharpness(image,x)
if isempty(x)
    x=0.2;
end
x=x-0.2;
image=imsharpen(image,'radius',2,'Amount',x);
end
```

The functions of increase decrease Contrast are same as of Sharpness.

Comment: I removed the image processing tag because your post is more concerned about GUI mechanics rather than processing images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using globals, Matlab provides ways to store data directly on your GUI objects.

[This page](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/share-data-among-callbacks.html#bt9p4xi) has a good overview of these methods.

The most appropriate way to share data between calls is to use `setappdata(hObject, name, value)` to store values on you GUI object and use `getappdata(hObject, name)` to retrieve them.

Another method is to use the `guidata(hObject, data)` function allowing you to store a single variable or struct. However, GUIDE GUI's use this function to store a handles object, so the setappdata method is preferred.

[EDIT based on comment from @Hoki]

Comment: `guidata` is better left for `handles` type of object. To pass other type of data across your GUI subfunctions, [`setappdata`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setappdata.html) and [`getappdata`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getappdata.html) are a better choice.

Comment: @Hoki yes I see, basically letting you store name-value pairs on a handle object. much more flexible.